# Multiple radiobutton selecion issue- dynamic radiobutton creation

Tags: android, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I am getting issue with radiobutton. I have created dynamic radiobuttons but i am able to multiple select.I need to check only one as per radiobutton functionality.
Here is my code:

```
 List<String> answers = Constants_Variables.missionMainResponse.getResponse().getData().get(early_pos).getQuestions().get(position).getANS();
        ViewGroup answer_radio_group = (ViewGroup) itemView.findViewById(R.id.answer_radio_group);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(context);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[answers.size()];
        Log.v("", TAG + "=Answers list size=" + answers.size());
        for (int j = 0; j < answers.size(); j++) {
            Log.v("", TAG + "=Answers=" + j);
            rb[j] = new RadioButton(context);
            rb[j].setText(answers.get(j) + "");
            rb[j].setId(j);
            ll.addView(rb[j]);
        }
        rb[0].setChecked(true);
        answer_radio_group.addView(ll);
```

Please help me out  I want to select only one option.
Thanks.

Comment: Use a single choice ListView, instead.

Comment: `R.id.answer_radio_group` is it `RadioGroup`?

Comment: Yes it is radiogroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add `RadioButtons` in `RadioGroup` first and than in other view or layout.

`answer_radio_group.addView(ll);` this line should be inside for loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < answers.size(); j++) {
        Log.v("", TAG + "=Answers=" + j);
        rb[j] = new RadioButton(context);
        rb[j].setText(answers.get(j) + "");
        rb[j].setId(j);
        answer_radio_group.addView(rb[j]);

    }
    rb[0].setChecked(true);
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Gives this error. i tried earlier.

Comment: ll.addView(answer_radio_group);

Comment: you have already added radioGroup in some view in your layout, so you can skip that line.